# Success message continues fire despite error state in Semantic-React-UI form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, semantic-ui-react, react-state

I am trying to get the appropriate messages to fire depending on the state of my form component for front end validation on form submit.

One of the main validations I'm working on is checking if a email exists and if so one should continue to see the error message fire. If it doesn't exist in the database a success message should fire; And of course if the other validations pass!.

I am using [Semantic-UI React Forms](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-error) to help with validation.

These are the key and values which I have set on the state object in my form component:

```
this.state = {
  fadeUp: 'fade up',
  duration: 500,
  username: '',
  password: '',
  usernameError: false,
  passwordError: false,
  formSuccess: false,
  formError: false,
  userNameDup: false,
}
```

This is my submit handler which fires upon submit:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var error = false

 var { username, password, userNameDup } = this.state

 var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/


if (!username.match(mailFormat)) {
  this.setState({ usernameError: true });
  error = true;
} else {
  this.setState({ usernameError: false });
}

if (password.length < 8) {
  this.setState({ passwordError: true });
  error = true;
} else {
  this.setState({ passwordError: false })
}

if (error) {
  this.setState({ formSuccess: false });
  return;
} else {
  this.setState({ formSuccess: true });
}

window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/users/registration', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ username_email: username, password: password })
})
  .then(this.handleErrors)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(`response ${response}`)
    return response.json()
  }).then(function (data) {

    console.log('User created:', data)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

   setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ username: '', password: '' }) })

 }

handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    if (response.status === 409) {
      console.log("response.status ", response.status);
      this.setState({
      userNameDup: true, formError: true, formSuccess:false
    });
    return;
  }
 } else {
  this.setState({
    userNameDup: false, formError:false
  })
 }
   return response;
 }
```

This is a portion of the form view/markup:

```
  {console.log("formSuccess 1", formSuccess)}

<Form size='large'
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  error={userNameDup || formError}>
  {console.log("formSuccess 2", formSuccess)}

  <Segment stacked>
    <Form.Input fluid icon='user'
      iconPosition='left'
      placeholder='E-mail address, e.g. joe@schmoe.com'
      name='username'
      value={username}
      onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      error={usernameError}
    />

    <Transition visible={usernameError}
      animation='scale'
      duration={duration}>
      <Message error content='username_Email is in incorrect format e.g. joe@schmoe.com' />
    </Transition>

    <Form.Input fluid icon='lock'
      iconPosition='left'
      placeholder='Password'
      name='password'
      value={password}
      onBlur={this.handleBlur}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      error={passwordError}
    />

    <Transition visible={passwordError}
      animation='scale'
      duration={duration}>
      <Message error content='Password needs to be greater than eight characters.' />
    </Transition>

    <Button color='teal'
      fluid size='large'
      disabled={!username || !password}>
      Register
      {/* {isLoggedIn ? `Register` : `Log-in`} */}
    </Button>

    <Transition visible={userNameDup || formError}
      unmountOnHide={true}
      animation='scale'
      duration={duration}>
      <Message
        error
        centered="true" header='This email exists.'
        content='Please re-enter another email address.' />
    </Transition>

    <Transition visible={formSuccess}
      unmountOnHide={true}
      animation='scale'
      duration={duration}>
      <Message
        success
        header='Your user registration was successful.'
        content='You may now log-in with the username you have chosen.' />
    </Transition>
  </Segment>
</Form>
```

I supplied a [image: gif] and you can see the `formSuccess` key jumps to `true` for a second which causes the problem. But I thought my `handleError` is taking care of that on submit?

handleError again:

```
 handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.status === 409) {
        console.log("response.status ", response.status);
        this.setState({
          userNameDup: true, formError: true, formSuccess:false /* why doesn't it stay falsey? */
        });
        return;
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        userNameDup: false, formError:false
      })
    }
    return response;
  }
```

Excerpt from handle submit:

```
window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/users/registration', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ username_email: username, password: password })
})
  .then(this.handleErrors) /* Shouldn't this be where it changes to false? */
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(`response ${response}`)
    return response.json()
  }).then(function (data) {

    console.log('User created:', data)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Also shouldn't the message animate every time one would hit register?

Please help!!! And thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (error) {
    this.setState({ formSuccess: false });
    return;
} else {
    this.setState({ formSuccess: true });
}
```

When you hit submit, the initial value for the `error` variable is false, so it changes the `formSuccess` state to true until the promise is resolved - when `handleErrors` is called and changes it back to false. You should only set `formSuccess` to true after you fetch the data from db, that is, inside `.then()` block to avoid async issues.

One approach to solving it is to display the success message after you fetched the data and validated the user is new like so:

```
handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    if (response.status === 409) {
      console.log("response.status ", response.status);
      this.setState({
      userNameDup: true, formError: true, formSuccess:false
    });
    return;
  }
 } else {
  this.setState({
    userNameDup: false, formError:false, formSuccess: true
  })
 }
   return response;
 }
```

And then your frontend validation is restricted to only showing the error message.

```
if (!username.match(mailFormat)) {
  this.setState({ usernameError: true, formSuccess: false } });
} else {
  this.setState({ usernameError: false });
}

if (password.length < 8) {
  this.setState({ passwordError: true, formSuccess: false } });
} else {
  this.setState({ passwordError: false })
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks my friend! Could you add what you meant for the `.then()` block? And how should I handle the `handleErrors` ||  the `if(error)`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Felipe! Its working now!